# JS completing slideshow function

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow

For js slideshow, I have been trying to make it work as follow:

**When first loaded: three images total**

```
<div class="images" style="display:block;"><img src="img_1.jpg"></div>
<div class="images" style="display:none;"><img src="img_2.jpg"></div>
<div class="images" style="display:none;"><img src="img_3.jpg"></div>

<a class="prev" onclick="moveSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="moveSlides(1)">❯</a>
```

When images are first loaded, the first image has `display:block` while other two had `none` by default.

```
//when next/prev button is clicked
function moveSlides(n) {
    slideShow(n);
};              

function slideShow(n) {                                 
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("images");

    // Display none for current image
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // display block for next image
    slides[n].style.display = "block";

};
```

The idea is that when the `next` or `prev` button is clicked, it will turn every image into `display:none` then change the next image to `display:block`.

I am having a bit of hard time accomplishing following things:

1. Detecting what image is currently being displayed so that when either `next` or `prev` button is clicked, it knows which image to display.
2. When it goes through the last image, it should go back to the first image.
3. Any other issues?

Comment: why not use one of many plugins available on the internet? (full of features or lightweight ones)

Comment: it's just not flexible enough for what I am doing or need to do. I tried few plugins but didn't cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend using a CSS class to control which one is visible:

```
.images         { display: none; }
.images.visible { display: block; }
```

That way you can use it as a selector in the JS to find which one was previously visible before you switch to the new one.

You can also use `nextElementSibling` and `previousElementSibling` to find the element that should be visible next.

```
function slideShow(n) {
    var slide = document.querySelector('.images.visible');
    slide.classList.remove('visible');
    if (n > 0) {
        if (slide.nextSibling) {
            slide.nextSibling.classList.add('visible');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.images').classList.add('visible');
        }
    } else {
        if (slide.previousSibling) {
            slide.previousSibling.classList.add('visible');
        } else {
            var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
            slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('visible');
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids using a loop or selecting more than you need, except in the case that it needs to wrap around to the beginning or end.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.

Comment: I updated, because I forgot about the requirement to loop back to the beginning or end.

Comment: Haha thank you. I was working on the loop portion myself, but your does look good. I will give it a try! :)